# mysql view with fulltext index

Tags: mysql, view, full-text-search

I need to create mysql view with fulltext index. Are there way to create view in mysql with fulltext index. 
Like table altering can I alter view to add full text index??

```
ALTER TABLE news ADD FULLTEXT(headline, story);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the manual:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html)

D.5 Restrictions on Views

View processing is not optimized:

- It is not possible to create an index on a view.
- Indexes can be used for views processed using the merge algorithm. However, a view that is processed with the temptable algorithm is unable to take advantage of indexes on its underlying tables (although indexes can be used during generation of the temporary tables).